# VBA/VB6 Transferência de estado de um documento de conta corrente

Tags: vb.net

Estou a desenvolver uma rotina para permitir fazer mudança de estado de um documento de compras, existente em Pendentes, por exemplo do estado Pendente para não aprovado.

O código:

```
Function CriaDocumentoMudancaEstadoPRI(TipoDocTrans As String,strNovoEstado as String, Modulo As String, TipoDoc As String, NumDocInt As Long, Serie As String, strTipoEntidade As String, strEntidade As String) As Boolean

Dim msg As String
Dim objPen As GCPBE900.GcpBEPendente
Dim objDocTrans As New GCPBE900.GcpBEDocumentoTransf

Dim objLinhasTransO As New GCPBE900.GcpBELinhaTransf
Dim objLinhasTransD As New GCPBE900.GcpBELinhaTransf

Dim rs As Object
Dim IDTransf  As String

    Set rs = MotorERP.Consulta("SELECT NewID() ID")
    IDTransf = rs!ID
    Set rs = Nothing


    If MotorERP.Comercial.Pendentes.Existe("000", Modulo, TipoDoc, Serie, NumDocInt) Then
      Set objPen = MotorERP.Comercial.Pendentes.Edita("000", "C", TipoDoc, Serie, NumDocInt)

      '-----------------------------------------
      '1- preenche o cabecalho do documento
      '-----------------------------------------
      With objDocTrans

        .TipoDoc = TipoDocLiq
        .Filial = objPen.Filial
        .Serie = objPen.Serie
        .TipoEntidade = strTipoEntidade
        .Entidade = strEntidade
        .TipoLancamento = objPen.TipoLancamento

        .Moeda = objPen.Moeda
        .MoedaDaUEM = objPen.MoedaDaUEM
        .Cambio = objPen.Cambio
        .CambioMAlt = objPen.CambioMAlt
        .CambioMBase = objPen.CambioMBase

        .DataDoc = objPen.DataDoc
        .Observacoes = objPen.Observacoes
        .ModoPag = ""
        .ContaBancaria = ""
        .EstadoDestino = strNovoEstado
        .TotalDoc = objPen.ValorPendente
        .Utilizador = strUsername
        .ModoPag = ""

        .ID = IDTransf
        .TipoConta = "C"
        .DataDoc = Date
        .Modulo = objPen.Modulo
        .TipoContaDestino = objPen.TipoConta
        .TransferenciaEstado = True
        .Modulo = "M"
        .EntidadeDestino = .Entidade

      End With

      '2- adiciona linha com estado atual
      Set objLinhasTransO = CreateObject("GcpBE900.GcpBELinhaTransf")
      With objLinhasTransO
            .TipoDocOrig = objPen.TipoDoc
            .NumDocOrig = objPen.NumDoc
            .NumDocOrigInt = objPen.NumDocInt
            .ModoPag = objPen.Modulo
            .MoedaDocOrig = objPen.Moeda
            .MoedaDaUEMDocOrig = False
            .CambioDocOrig = objPen.Cambio
            .CambioMAltDocOrig = objPen.CambioMAlt
            .CambioMBaseDocOrig = objPen.CambioMBase
            If .CambioMBaseDocOrig = 0 Then .CambioMBaseDocOrig = 1
            .FilialOrig = objPen.Filial
            .ModuloOrig = objPen.Modulo
            .ValorOrig = -Valor
            .ValorRec = -Valor
            .SerieOrig = objPen.Serie
            .Estado = objPen.Estado
            .FilialOrig = "000"
            .ModuloOrig = "C"
            .NumDocOrigInt = objPen.NumDocInt
            .NumDocOrig = objPen.NumDoc
            .PendenteGerado = False
            .SerieOrig = objPen.Serie
            .TipoConta = objPen.TipoConta
            If .CambioDocOrig = 0 Then .CambioDocOrig = 1
            If .CambioMAltDocOrig = 0 Then .CambioMAltDocOrig = 1
            If .CambioMBaseDocOrig = 0 Then .CambioMBaseDocOrig = 1

            .TipoConta = objPen.TipoConta
            .Estado = objPen.Estado

            .TipoEntidadeOrigem = "F"
            .TipoEntidadeComercial = ""
            .EntidadeComercial = ""
            .EntidadeOrigem = objPen.Entidade

            .FilialOrig = "000"
            .ModuloOrig = "C"
            .TipoDocOrig = objPen.TipoDoc
            .TransfereEntidade = False

            .IdHistorico = objPen.IdHistorico
            .ModoPag = ""
            .NumPrestacaoOrig = objPen.NumPrestacao
            .IDDocTransf = IDTransf
      End With

      Set objLinhasTransD = CreateObject("GcpBE900.GcpBELinhaTransf")
      With objLinhasTransD
            .TipoDocOrig = objPen.TipoDoc
            .NumDocOrig = objPen.NumDoc
            .NumDocOrigInt = objPen.NumDocInt
            .ModoPag = objPen.Modulo
            .MoedaDocOrig = objPen.Moeda
            .MoedaDaUEMDocOrig = False
            .CambioDocOrig = objPen.Cambio
            .CambioMAltDocOrig = objPen.CambioMAlt
            .CambioMBaseDocOrig = objPen.CambioMBase
            If .CambioMBaseDocOrig = 0 Then .CambioMBaseDocOrig = 1
            .FilialOrig = objPen.Filial
            .ModuloOrig = objPen.Modulo
            .ValorOrig = -Valor
            .ValorRec = 0
            .SerieOrig = objPen.Serie
            '-----------------------------------
            ' Define novo estado do documento
            '-----------------------------------
            .Estado = strNovoEstado
            .FilialOrig = "000"

            .ModuloOrig = "C"

            .NumDocOrigInt = objPen.NumDocInt
            .NumDocOrig = objPen.NumDoc
            .PendenteGerado = False
            .SerieOrig = objPen.Serie
            .TipoConta = objPen.TipoConta
            If .CambioDocOrig = 0 Then .CambioDocOrig = 1
            If .CambioMAltDocOrig = 0 Then .CambioMAltDocOrig = 1
            If .CambioMBaseDocOrig = 0 Then .CambioMBaseDocOrig = 1
            .TipoConta = objPen.TipoConta
            .TipoEntidadeOrigem = "F"
            .TipoEntidadeComercial = ""
            .EntidadeComercial = ""
            .EntidadeOrigem = objPen.Entidade

            .FilialOrig = "000"
            .ModuloOrig = "C"
            .TipoDocOrig = objPen.TipoDoc
            .TransfereEntidade = False
            .NumPrestacaoOrig = objPen.NumPrestacao

            .IdHistorico = objPen.IdHistorico
            .IDDocTransf = IDTransf
      End With



      objLinhasTransD.Estado = strNovoEstado



      objDocTrans.DocumentosTransferir.Insere objLinhasTransO
      objDocTrans.DocumentosTransferir.Insere objLinhasTransD


      objDocTrans.TipoEntidadeDestino = "F"

      objDocTrans.TotalDoc = objPen.ValorPendente

      Dim strErros As String

      If MotorERP.Comercial.Transferencias.ValidaActualizacao(objDocTrans, strErros) Then

        MotorERP.Comercial.Transferencias.Actualiza objDocTrans, strErros
        CriaDocumentoMudancaEstado = True

      Else
        CriaDocumentoMudancaEstado = False

      End If

    Else
      MsgBox "Nao existe pendente", vbExclamation
    End If


End Function
```

Exemplo da sua utilização:

> CriaDocumentoMudancaEstadoPRI "NAP", "C", "VFA", 1, "2019", "F",
>   "F00111"

Obtenho o erro:

> O Documento NAP -  nao possui dados corretos para a transferencia,  a
>   Entidade Destino a Conta Destino e o Estado Destino sao iguais as sua
>   origens Linha2 : Nao existe referencia em Pendentes para o documento
>   000 A VF1 999285/A O valor transferido do documento original VF1
>   999285/A nao pode ser nulo. Nao pode realizar transferencias de estado
>   conjuntamente com transferencias de outro tipo.

O que é que faltará no código?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde,

No cabeçalho do documento falta ativar a propriedade MantemEntidadePendentes:

```
objDocTrans.MantemEntidadePendentes = True
```

No caso das linhas, a forma correta é usando o método AdicionaLinha:

```
Set objDocTrans = BSO.Comercial.Transferencias.AdicionaLinha(objDocTrans, objPen.Filial, objPen.Modulo, objPen.TipoDoc, objPen.Serie, objPen.NumDocInt, objPen.NumPrestacao, objPen.Estado, objPen.NumTransferencia)
```

Depois deste AdicionaLinha terá ainda que se atribuir estas propriedades:

```
objDocTrans.DocumentosTransferir(1).ValorOrig = objPen.ValorPendente * -1
objDocTrans.DocumentosTransferir(1).ValorRec = objPen.ValorPendente * -1
objDocTrans.DocumentosTransferir(1).IdHistorico = objPen.IdHistorico
```

Comment: @DavidVieira era mesmo isso. Obrigado.